# GEE vs GLMM in this example

Tags: glmm, generalized-estimating-equations

I am fitting a model with a dichotomous outcome, large number of subjects measured at differing visit (visit 1-14) with four other categorical and cont outcome variable....the main question is if the probability of infection varies in one variable of interest....thoughts on model selection GLMM vs GEE?